Firebase firestore trigger onDocumentUpdated not triggered when document is updated
exports.updateUser = onDocumentUpdated("users/{userId}", (event)=> {
    logger.info('Execution Started updateUnitTenant');
});

Cloud function is not triggered when updating a document in users collection.
The function deployes without a problem but the trigger isn't working. I tried to check the logs but nothing there.

Can  you please edit your question and add the code that updates the a user?

@AlexMamo Just this only, I removed everything and deployed just an info log, but nothing on the firebase side

Is the function, I was referring to the code the updates the user, which in terms triggers the function.
